# How to find the first longest consecutive years?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

MS SQL Server 2017+

The table ONLY has one column.

The data is already sorted.

The column contains some duplicate years.

Please see the sample data below:

```
create table test1 (year int)

insert into test1 values
(1992), --1
(1993), --2
(1994), --3
(1995), --4
(1995), --4
(1997), --1
(1998), --2
(2000), --1
(2001), --2
(2002), --3
(2003), --4
(2003), --4
(2008)  --1
```

Expected Result:

```
1992
1993
1994
1995
```

Please note the period of 2000-2003 also has 4 consecutive years but I only want the first longest one which is 1992-1995 in the sample data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  A table is not ordered unless a column specifies that ordering.  In your case, that column appears to be `year`.

I think the simplest solution is to get the year on one row.  You can find this by subtracting a sequence number from the years -- constant values for the difference indicate sequences of years.

The rest is just ordering and `select top`:

```
select top (1) min(year), max(year)
from (select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by year) as seqnum
      from test1 t
     ) t
group by year - seqnum
order by max(year) - min(year) desc, min(year) asc;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4afa05e877440a08ff40ba379f342a5d) is a db<>fiddle.

Getting the original rows is a bit trickier.  Here is one method:

```
select top (1) with ties year, max(year) over (partition by year - seqnum) - min(year) over (partition by year - seqnum) as cnt
from (select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by year) as seqnum
      from test1 t
     ) t
order by max(year) over (partition by year - seqnum) - min(year) over (partition by year - seqnum) desc,
         min(year) over (partition by year - seqnum)
```

And a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6f9005ee91f3f8e986ea44c2303661f6) for that.